# huge discrepancy between pagesviews on Google Analytics vs. Piwik

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, matomo

We have 2 trackers on our websites starting from this year (assessing which one we should go with in the long run), and I noticed that there is a huge discrepancy in pageviews, visitor counts, sessions, etc.

For example, pageviews it was `320k in GA` vs. `150k in Piwik`.

GA is not always having a larger number though. For January this year, it's `630k in GA` vs. `790k in Piwik`, but there's still a huge gap.

Any idea on what the reasons could be? Or from where I should start looking into the discrepancy? We need the numbers for reporting to senior management...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this article help https://matomo.org/faq/troubleshooting/faq_50/?

Comment: @HenryWoody unfortunately it doesn't help much... I've checked the settings according to the article - bot and spider is disabled in GA; no IP excluded from Piwik; js codes are correct. One thing to add to my question is that even the unique pageviews are so different... 280k in GA vs. 125k in Piwik... I still don't have an answer.

Comment: Please double check if the tracking code is added in all the pages you're tracking and it matches both the tools and also make sure the date range of the report is same.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience the most common thing was the Do Not track support, Piwik (matomo) has it on by default ( ignores browsers with DNT flag) while GA has it off by default (tracks all browsers) some browsers have DNT flag turned on by default so the discrepancy can be quite high.